# Pressure Head, Elevation Potential Head, and Differential Pressure Gauge -- How to account for all three?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

My liquid flow and measurement system is situated as shown here:
[image]

Flow is occurring vertically upwards, against gravity, due to an imposed pressure difference $\Delta p$. Flow moves into and out-of the test sample through the lines shown on the right.

As seen on the left-hand side of the test sample, I have a differential pressure gauge, at the elevation $z_{\Delta p}$, which is below the sample. The intent of the differential pressure gauge is to measure the difference in pressures on either side of the sample, $\Delta p = p_{in} - p_{out}$.

However, I'm unsure of what the differential pressure gauge is actually measuring since there are changes in elevation in the tubing leading from either end of the test sample, and then connecting with the differential pressure gauge. I know there is a pressure associated with the density of the liquid, the change in elevation of the liquid, and gravity, i.e., $p=\rho g \Delta z$.

Ultimately, what I am needing to know is the change in fluid potential $\equiv \Delta \Phi = \Delta p + \rho g \Delta z$ that is driving the fluid to flow from one end of the test sample to the other.

The inlet and outlet flow and $\Delta p$-pressure lines all lead into & out-of the sample along the same elevation, $z_{out}$.

I know the values for $\Delta p$ (as measured by the gauge), $z_{\Delta p}, z_{in}, z_{out}, g$ and $\rho$, **how do I use this information to properly determine the change in fluid potential $\Delta \Phi = \Delta p + \rho g \Delta z$ that is driving the fluid to flow from one end of the test sample to the other?**

The test sample is a porous medium (rock), and the condition of flow is that of Stokes flow -- the rate of flow is sufficiently low to be directly proportional to the hydraulic gradient across the sample. The "permeability" of the tubing leading into/out-from the rock is many orders of magnitude greater than the permeability of the rock such that the frictional losses in the tubing is negligible.

Comment: I don't think that set up is workable for your purpose unless you accept the approximation/simplification: $z_{\Delta p}-z_{in}\approx 0$.

Comment: Alternatively, one would have to know the pressure at $z_{\Delta p}$.

Comment: If the flow velocity through your vessel is very low, the uncertainty in the dp measurement will totally swamp the signal you are trying to measure.  Why are you not using a flow meter to measure flow rate?

Comment: @DavidWhite I am using a flow meter, but I didn't think it was necessary for this question to talk about all the other aspects of the flow loop. I only mentioned the information I thought would be necessary to answer my question. Is the flow meter necessary information for this question?

Comment: @Gert As I don't know what you know, I suppose I can kindly ask if you could provide an answer/explanation if: 1) I accept the approximation/simplification: $z_{\Delta p}-z_{in}~0$; 2) if I know the pressure at $z_{\Delta p}$.

Comment: @Armadillo, no.  However, if you want to use your dp calculation as a check on the flow meter, the uncertainty of the dp measurement will leave you guessing.  In principle, your calculation will work, but I note that your equation assumes an absolutely constant and absolutely known value for liquid density, which is probably a big assumption in this case.

Comment: @DavidWhite Thank you. Can you clarify what you mean by "dp calculation"? I have a differential pressure gauge that measures the pressure difference $\Delta p$. I am looking to calculate the difference in flow potential $\Delta \Phi$. The liquid is water, and the applied pressures are such that I assume water compression to be negligible (I assume constant water density). Likewise, I assume the gravity acceleration to be constant as well (even though it changes with elevation).

Comment: @Armadillo, in your equation ΔΦ=Δp+ρgΔz, you are implicitly assuming that the liquid density is absolutely constant and known.  Assuming that you are going to calculate dp as Δp=ΔΦ-ρgΔz, there will be issues.  And note - I have a chemical engineering background, and "dp" is a general term for differential pressure (aka pressure drop).

Comment: @DavidWhite Why are you assuming I am going to calculate dp ($\Delta p$) as $\Delta \Phi - \rho g \Delta z$? I have said that I am wanting to calculate $\Delta \Phi$. I have a measure of $\Delta p$, but what the actual measurement of $\Delta p$ is is what I am asking about since there are changes in elevations built into the system. Also, calculating dp as you've described while assuming density to be constant and known does not necessarily cause issues, does it? I would think it only brings an associated error (uncertainty) in the calculated value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130887/discussion-between-david-white-and-armadillo).